# Why my divs won't stack on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, display

I'm a beginner web developper, and I'm working on a homepage. Yet I'm stuck: for some reasons, my divs just won't stack on top of each other like they should (at least I think so), the blue one keep appearing in the center of the page, no matter what I do. I tried a whole lot of things, and nothing solved it.

Help!
Best Regards,

-Solar Palms

PS: There's my code ...

```css
body{
 background:url(trees.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-postion: center;
}
h1{
color: white;

}
main{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15%;
}
.lol{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 clear: left;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Home</title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="Home.css">
<!-- The JQuery Link -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- HUGE NAVBAR -->
 <div class='lol'>
 <header id="header" style="position:sticky; top:0;">
  <div class='container'>
      </style>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header" >
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GREEN Seed</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-left:15%;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>

        </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="margin-left:20%">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
           </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
 </header>
</div>
 <main>
  <h1>Are you ready to help to save Our planet!</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Take actions!</button>

 </main>
</div>
<div class='lol' style='background-color: blue; height:100px;'>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? also height: 100% does nothing when it comes to height it needs to be in pixles @Solar

Comment: I want both divs to be stacked on top each other, so when you scroll, you can see the one below, in this case the footer. And thanks for  your answer ^^

Comment: if you have structured your code correctly and there is no HTML errors, having two `<div>` on top of each other will stack them by default. Only way to have them side by side is to change `display: inline-block; float: right;` this will put them side ways. So if your divs are not showing correctly you most likely have an html error somewhere.. Also the code you pasted if you run it it shows correctly no issues

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have nothing of the sort (display:inline-block, etc.), At least from what I remember. And they don't appear side to side. But one hiding partially the one beneath it. So yeah, I just don't get what's the problem '--